# How to use both/either in negative sentences?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, sentence

I recently saw this sentence,

"the system has not been yet used in both large and small cities".

I wonder if both can be used in negative sentences like this? If not, how can "either" be used in such a sentence where two names are mentioned afterwards? we cannot say EITHER large And small cities. also both refers to positive sentences.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The system has *not yet* been used in ***either*** large ***or*** small cities // the system has been used in *neither* large *nor* small cities **as yet.**

Comment: The adverb placement (*_the system has not been yet used_) would suggest that it was not composed by a native English speaker, and that the quantifier-negative scope problem is not the only one this sentence has.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing "both" with "either" would change the meaning of the sentence. If a system has not been used in both large and small cities, then it may have been used in one or the other, just not in *both*. If a system has not been used in either large or small cities, then it has been used in neither. In the latter case, one might opt for a "neither/nor" construction.